# invalid use of non-static data member while using const variable

Tags: c++

```
class Try {
    const int no = 5;
    int arr[no];
};
```

Here is a simple class , but I get this compilation error. `no` is constant so I thought it should not be the problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`arr` must have the same size in all instances of your class. `no` is const but that only means it never changes after an instance is created. It **doesn't** mean that it is the same for all instances all the time. For example, `no` can be set in the initializer list of the constructor

```
Foo::Foo(int size) : no(size)
{}
```

For this reason, unless you make `no` static, you can't use it as array size because that would imply potentially differently sized arrays in each instance.